# Mongodb queries are returning nothing

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently taking a course in university.mongodb but suddenly the queries stopped working. I was practicing with the UpdateOne and noticed that it didn't worked and didn't modified the document I was trying to modify. I'm now trying to do a simple find but it returns a 0 like there's no document in the database, and I already checked if the database was set in the one I had to use.

I reconnected and used the db I needed but the query didn't worked neither.

db.movieDetails.find({title: "The Martian"})

It's not a syntax problem. I expected the output to be 1 because there is only 1 document with that name but it returned a 0.

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW7nb.jpg)

Comment: Did you switch your database before running the find? If not, enter the command, use <Databasename> and then run your find query. Apart from this I don't see anything else could be causing this

Comment: I previously used the command use video and it returned the message db switched to video and tried after that, but it keeps returning nothing when I run whatever query I want.

Comment: Do you get the document when you run the command db.movieDetails.find({}) ?

Comment: No it just doesn't return anything, is there an option to upload an image here?

Comment: When I run the command to find anything, it sometimes returns a 0 and sometimes it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.movieDetails.find({title: "The Martian"})
```

What you are doing is:

```
db.MovieDetails.find({title: "The Martian"})
```

Collection name is case sensitive